# Orchard CMS one ContentPart on several View

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

Exist model - \Models\HeaderPart.cs.
In Driver, want create CategoriesMenuDriver and use HeaderPart:

```
  public class CategoriesMenuDriver : ContentPartDriver<HeaderPart>
    {
    private readonly dynamic shapeFactory;
    private readonly IMenuAccessor menuAccessor;

    public CategoriesMenuDriver(
          IShapeFactory shapeFactory,
          IMenuAccessor menuAccessor)
      {
        this.shapeFactory = shapeFactory;
        this.menuAccessor = menuAccessor;
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(HeaderPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {
          return this.ContentShape("Parts_CategoriesMenu", () => shapeHelper.Parts_CategoriesMenu(
            MenuItems: this.menuAccessor.GetMenu<NavigationMenuItem>("UserAccount")));
        }
    }
```

But in CategoriesMenu view

```
  var headerPart = (HeaderPart)Model.ContentItem.HeaderPart;
```

Model.ContentItem is  null.

Can i get HeaderPart in View CategoriesMenu?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the part like this:

```
HeaderPart part = Model.ContentPart;
```

Although `Model.ContentItem` shouldn't be null there, which is strange

**EDIT**
If it also null you can try just setting it yourself:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(HeaderPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
        return ContentShape("Parts_CategoriesMenu", () => shapeHelper.Parts_CategoriesMenu(
            MenuItems: this.menuAccessor.GetMenu<NavigationMenuItem>("UserAccount"),
            ContentPart: part       
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Model.ContentPart is null too

Comment: In View\Parts\Header.cshtml:
  var headerPart = (HeaderPart)Model.ContentItem.HeaderPart; // Not null. May be is dependency on Model name?

Comment: How orcharcd cms transmits Model.ContentItem to View\Parts?  From driver? Is it correct ?   protected override DriverResult Display(HeaderPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {
          return this.ContentShape("Parts_CategoriesMenu", () => shapeHelper.Parts_CategoriesMenu(
            MenuItems: this.menuAccessor.GetMenu<NavigationMenuItem>("UserAccount")));
        }

Comment: Well I mean you can always just pass it in yourself, I've edited my answer